# localhost:3000 refused to connect after installing devise gem in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise, rubygems

My rails application was working fine before I installed the devise gem. After installing the devise gem, the rails server connects correctly in the terminal but it refuses to connect in the browser. Already tried switching to another port but to no avail. How do I connect it properly in localhost:3000 again during development? I am using postgresql for my database.

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.3.2 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.3.1 (ruby 3.0.1-p64) ("Sweetnighter")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 3519
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000 Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Comment: There's no reason why the devise gem would interfere with the connection. What do you mean when you say that you are able to connect in the browser? Is this using cURL?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are going though the entire devise installation the wrong way. Try to find at which point it fails to work. Uninstall devise.

1. Remove in your Gemfile: gem 'devise'
2. Run in terminal: bundle
3. Run in terminal: gem uninstall devise(To make sure devise isn't in your app)
4. Is it working now? If no then devise isn't the problem. If yes, proceed to the next step.
5. Add in your Gemfile: gem 'devise'
6. Run in terminal: bundle
7. At this point, a number of instructions will appear in the console. Among these instructions, you'll need to set up the default URL options for the Devise mailer in each environment. Here is a possible configuration for config/environments/development.rb:

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

In the following command you will replace MODEL with the class name used for the application’s users (it’s frequently User but could also be Admin). This will create a model (if one does not exist) and configure it with the default Devise modules. The generator also configures your config/routes.rb file to point to the Devise controller.

Run in terminal: rails generate devise MODEL

Next, check the MODEL for any additional configuration options you might want to add, such as confirmable or lockable. If you add an option, be sure to inspect the migration file (created by the generator if your ORM supports them) and uncomment the appropriate section. For example, if you add the confirmable option in the model, you'll need to uncomment the Confirmable section in the migration.

Run in terminal: rails db:migrate

You should restart your application after changing Devise's configuration options (this includes stopping spring). Otherwise, you will run into strange errors, for example, users being unable to login and route helpers being undefined.